# Automation to spin up EC2 Volumes (dedicated machines) for each webproject

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web-hosting, plesk

I'm planning to set up a sort of private hosting environment for me and my webprojects and am wondering if there is a great/easy solution to spin up new ec2 volumes (always a dedicated volume/machine) for each of my webprojects fast.

I'm right now using one EC2 with Plesk (Ubuntu) installed, that I really love. I simply create a Domain and the project is basically setup with users, ftp-access, etc.

I wonder if there is a way to have sort of the "same " setup but for each domain it basically creates a dedicated hosting project.

Any clever ideas on how to create such a thing?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know *Plesk* but you can certainly automate instance creation. Usually you'll use **[CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/)** or **[Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/)** to do that - they will create the EC2 Instance, IAM Roles, Security Groups, etc, the same config every time.

For the actual instance you've got a couple of options:

1. Create a **Gold Image** with your desired basic configuration that you want to use as a baseline for your projects. You can then use this image to spin up new instances and they will all come up the same.
2. You can use something like **[Packer](https://www.packer.io/)** to automatically create the **Gold Images** for you whenever your requirements change.
3. Have some **start up automation** that will take e.g. a domain name and use Plesk or something similar to automatically configure your environment.

Ideally you should have all the config and customer files in a separate storage (e.g. **[AWS EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/)**) instead of on the EC2 / EBS volumes and treat all your instances as immutable, disposable compute power. That will enable you to use **autoscaling**, **docker containers** and other advanced forms of automation. But that may be something to aim for later.

Hope that helps :)